# Discord Bot is Running But not Responding to Prompts

Tags: discord.py, bots

I'm making a bot to facilitate an inside joke on my Discord Server. Its meant to read the last 2 letters of the final word in a message and if they end with an er it responds "{last_word}, I hardly know her!" I can not get to bot to respond to any messages. There are no errors in its start up and the bot shows as Online in Repl.it and on my testing discord.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('TARA_BOT ONLINE')

async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
    return

    words = message.content.split()
    last_word = words[-1].lower() if words else ""

    if last_word.endswith("er"):
        response = f"{last_word} I hard know her"
        await message.channel.send(response) 

    # Continue processing other commands
    await client.process_commands(message)

client.run('Token')
```

Any assistance that can be provided here would be greatly appreciated

When I write a message in a general text channel the bot does not respond. I have tried varying lengths of phrases to see if the code is reading the chat incorrectly to avail.

Edit I have changed up the Intents section to include:

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('TARA_BOT ONLINE')

async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    words = message.content.split()
    last_word = words[-1].lower() if words else ""

    if last_word.endswith("er"):
        response = f"{last_word} I hard know her"
        await message.channel.send(response) 

    # Continue processing other commands
    await client.process_commands(message)

    client.run('Token')
```

However this still does not accept messages not respond to anything written. I checked the Developer portal and all the correct intents are ticked

**Final Edit**

The correct code is as follows. I did not add the @client.event decoration like a total dinkus. I also added a couple new links for added comedy:

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('TARA_BOT ONLINE')

@client.event  # Add this line to decorate on_message as an event handler
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    words = message.content.split()
    last_word = words[-1].lower() if words else ""

    if last_word.endswith("er") or last_word.endswith("or") or last_word.endswith("ar"):
        response = f"{last_word}, I hardly know her!"
        await message.channel.send(response)

    # Continue processing other commands
    await client.process_commands(message)


client.run('Token')
```

Comment: You need to enable the message content intent

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.default), `discord.Intents.default()` does not include the `message_content` intent, so your bot will not receive the contents of messages. You could try the following:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Comment: I'm not certain how to add this so it works. When attempting to add this code it starts to throw a bunch of errors and no longer recognizes the token and throws a permissions error:

Would you mind demonstrating how it should look?

Comment: You also need to enable the permission in the Discord Developer Portal. https://i.imgur.com/xb9ZGAi.png